# Issue with concatenating and replace in Pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, replace, unique, concatenation

I am stymied with something, and if I fix it one way, it breaks something else.

I have a set of data that lists file status by country.  What I want to do is, for each country in the Country column, print all missing files by each status in the VisitStatus column.  So for all rows where country=France, then for every visit that is "Complete", list the number of missing files.

There are two dataframes that I am concatenating into one combined set to work with and deliver final output.  I am concat'ing df_s and df_ins into df_combined.

When I grab a set of unique values for the Country and VisitStatus columns to loop over, then try to write out the results per country to an Excel file workbook, quirks in the data kick out a 'duplicate sheetname' error.  In one of the source dataframes, there is a status of "Do Not Review" in the VisitStatus column, but in the other source dataframe, it's named "Do not review", lowercase for the second two words.  When they're concatenated, this kicks out unique values of "Do Not Review" and "Do not review".  Then when the xslx writer tries to make the workbooks for the second one, it checks it against the existing  workbooks DISREGARDING CASE, finds the first one, decides they are the same since it is ignoring case, and kicks out the error saying that the 'Do not review' worksheet already exists.

If I run replace() and change all the "Do not review" values in the VisitStatus column into "Do Not Review" so they all match and don't give two results for that when I call unique(), it breaks and gives me a KeyError on VisitStatus.

So far I have read thread after thread about this and haven't been able to solve this.  I just tried running the replace() on the source dataframe, and then it throws an error saying that "status" is a float and can't be handled like a string.

I'm at a loss.  Thanks in advance!

```
#     COMBO
# Merge the screening and in study datasets
df_combined = pd.concat([df_s,df_ins], axis=0, ignore_index=True)
df_combined = df_combined.query('VisitStatus != "Hand Off  Information"')
print(df_combined.columns.values)

print("---------------------------------------------------------------------------------")
# Display and save out country and missing file status
statuses = df_combined['VisitStatus'].unique()
countries = df_combined['Country'].unique()
for status in statuses:
    print("X" + status + "X")
    print('\n')
print (statuses)
for country in countries:
    for status in statuses:
        print('\n')
        print("---> Missing Files for " + country + " all visits with status of: " + str(status))
        df_cmb = df_combined[(df_combined.Country==country) & (df_combined.VisitStatus==status)]
        print('\n')
        numRows=df_cmb.shape[0]
        if numRows > 0:
            print("----> Number of visits in " + str(status) + " subset: " + str(numRows))
            print("DRF Forms Missing: " + str(df_cmb['DRF-Form-Uploaded'].sum()) + " vs. " + str(numRows - df_cmb['DRF-Form-Uploaded'].sum()) + " collected")
            print("CSSRS Forms Missing: " + str(df_cmb['CSSRS-Form-Uploaded'].sum()) + " vs. " + str(numRows - df_cmb['CSSRS-Form-Uploaded'].sum()) + " collected")
            print("CDR Forms Missing: " + str(df_cmb['CDR-Form-Uploaded'].sum()) + " vs. " + str(numRows - df_cmb['CDR-Form-Uploaded'].sum()) + " collected")
            print("CDR Audio Missing: " + str(df_cmb['CDR-Audio-Uploaded'].sum()) + " vs. " + str(numRows - df_cmb['CDR-Audio-Uploaded'].sum()) + " collected")
            print("MMSE Forms Missing: " + str(df_cmb['MMSE-Form-Uploaded'].sum()) + " vs. " + str(numRows - df_cmb['MMSE-Form-Uploaded'].sum()) + " collected")
            print("MMSE Audio Missing: " + str(df_cmb['MMSE-Audio-Uploaded'].sum()) + " vs. " + str(numRows - df_cmb['MMSE-Audio-Uploaded'].sum()) + " collected")
            print("RBANS Forms Missing: " + str(df_cmb['RBANS-Form-Uploaded'].sum()) + " vs. " + str(numRows - df_cmb['RBANS-Form-Uploaded'].sum()) + " collected")
            print("RBANS Audio Missing: " + str(df_cmb['RBANS-Audio-Uploaded'].sum()) + " vs. " + str(numRows - df_cmb['RBANS-Audio-Uploaded'].sum()) + " collected")
            print("--------------------------------------")
            print('\n')
        else:
            print("No " + status + " files/visits for " + country)
        if country =="United States":
            country="USA"
        # something is borked in the next line - somehow there are two "Do Not Review" status types in the combined file, triggers an "already in use" for sheetname
        df_cmb.to_excel(combo_writer, header=True, index=False, sheet_name=str(country)[:3] + "-by-" + str(status))
```

Comment: It would be simpler if you could just show your input and expected output.

Answer (score 0):

Oh lord.  I'm answering my own question.

So I tinkered some more and nothing else made sense, so I started wondering if I was putting in the arguments for replace() correctly, and I had them backwards.  I assumed the "Do not review" needed to be changed to "Do Not Review", but it was the other way around...I assumed incorrectly as to which source file data needed to be modified.  Once I flipped them, it works.

Comment: If it was a typo, please consider deleting this question.